# Nesting different layouts

Tags: android, layout, nested

I am not sure how to nest different layouts.
i want to have one listlayout and one table layout side by side. I want ListLayout on left and  Table layout on right of listlayout for example

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

And One tablelayout

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Open..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-O"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Save..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-S"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

But if i do it like this then i don't get listlayout and table layout is on the left. I am just a beginner and may be i am doing it completely wrong. can anyone guide me please its urgent....

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a ScrollView or a TableLayout as the top parent. If it's a TableLayout, then you'll need a TableRow.

```
<TableLayout>
   <TableRow>
      {Add your ListView Here}

      {Add your nested TableLayout here}
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Since there is no TableColumn or TableCell, it should treat each child in the TableRow as a column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one overall layout, and then put sub-layouts inside of it.  One way to do what you want is to have the top level layout a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.  One thing to keep in mind, performance goes down a little as you add more and more layouts, so it is a good idea to try to minimize the number of layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the table and list layout in a LinearLayout?

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<!-- List view goes here -->
<!-- Table layout goes here -->
</LinearLayout>`

There is also the RelativeLayout, which lets you specify where sublayouts are positioned relative to other sublayouts. For example:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210117112714/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/relativelayout-in-android-xml.html

Comment: I tried to put code i showed above in relativelayout <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/listTable"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center">                                                                                                                But it doesnt help :(

Comment: @Jeena, when using a RelativeLayout you have to tell the objects where to position themselves, using "below", "toRightOf", "toLeftOf", etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Relative layout then use following parameters for Table and List Views in xml file.
For ListView-->android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
and for TableView,-->android:layout_toRightOf="ListView"
Also if this doesn't work,add one more
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
for tableView